# Labels redefined in Macro in C

Tags: c, visual-c++, macros, label, redefinition

Trying to use goto labels in a C macro (running MSVC) but if the macro is called multiple times in the same caller function, C2045 label redefined errors appear.

I've tried using __label__ from this example:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/local-labels-in-c/
but that label keyword is probably gcc only because MSVC reports label undefined.

I understand it's really obfuscated and silly but I'm writing a transpiler to convert MASM code into C. In MASM, labels are defined locally using the LOCAL directive, __label__ is used by GCC, but what does MSVC offer as a solution?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define     Loopy(AA) {              \
   RTSZ_0:;                          \
   if (AA >= 5) { goto RTSZ_1; }     \
   AA += 1;                          \
   goto RTSZ_0;                      \
   RTSZ_1:;                          \
}                               

int main()
{
    int AA = 0;

    Loopy(AA);
    Loopy(AA);

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the goto labels to be assigned a unique label so that when included multiple times, there would be no redefinition errors.

Is there a C keyword that can be applied to the macro or a workaround?
Something like:

```
            __Uniquelabel__       RTSZ_0; \
            __Uniquelabel__       RTSZ_1; \
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Most people would say that macros like that are a bad ide in the first place, let alone with gotos.  Let's see if we can figure out a better way of accomplishing your goal.

Comment: That macro is just a really awkward way to write a `while` loop. So the answer to this question is simply, "Don't do that!"

Comment: I understand it's really obfuscated and silly but I'm writing a transpiler to convert MASM code into C. In MASM, labels are defined locally using the LOCAL directive, __label__ is used by GCC, but what does MSVC offer as a solution? Thanks.

Comment: You should have said that in your question.

Comment: I doubt there's a way to do it in MSVC.  (I'm surprised there's a way to do it in gcc -- I'd never heard of that "unique label" thingie.)  You should keep your own variable which counts how many labels you've generated, and use it to construct unique ones yourself, with something like `sprintf(uniquelabel, "label%d", ++nlabels)`.

Comment: Sorry about that...currently looking into using this code:

    #define S1(x) #x
    #define S2(x) S1(x)
    #define RTSZ "RTSZ_" S2(__LINE__) ":"

 printf("%s", RTSZ);
 printf("%s", RTSZ);

which outputs

RTSZ_25:RTSZ_26:

Comment: Why are you fixated on these crazy, ugly macros?  I'm no expert on "transpilers" (never heard of those, either), but is there some rule that they have to be constructed using maximum preprocessor abuse?

Comment: I'll see if there's a better way. Spent 5 hours just now trying to get it to work.
M$ must be able to provide a method? Oh well...thanks again for the insights!

Comment: You should tag this question with one of the relevant msvc or visual-c tags.  Maybe someone who watches those tags can help.

Comment: I'm currently banned from asking further questions. Apparently writing poor questions like this one (-2) leads to a ban.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> currently looking into using this code:
>
> ```
> #define S1(x) #x
> #define S2(x) S1(x)
> #define RTSZ "RTSZ_" S2(__LINE__) ":"
> ```

Indeed something along the above lines can be used to generate unique labels, as long as there's not more than one macro invocation per source line:

```
#define RTSZ(i) RTSZ1(i, __LINE__)
#define RTSZ1(i, l) RTSZ2(i, l)
#define RTSZ2(i, l) RTSZ_##i##_##l

#define     Loopy(AA) {              \
   RTSZ(0):                          \
   if (AA >= 5) { goto RTSZ(1); }    \
   AA += 1;                          \
   goto RTSZ(0);                     \
   RTSZ(1): ;                        \
}
```

The intermediate `RTSZ1()` macro serves to expand the `__LINE__` macro, similar to the `S2()` in your approach.

Comment: Thanks Armali for the tips! I'll try that approach.

Comment: Working great now! :)